# Convergence of $\sum_{p>2} \frac{(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}}{p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Consider the sum $\sum_{p>2} \frac{(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}}{p}$ where $p$ runs only through all odd primes. Show that this sum converges.
The possibly best approach I have until now is via Partial summation, but dealing with number of primes
is troubling, especially for obtaining explicit bounds.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is $\sum_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p}$, where $\chi$ denotes the quadratic Dirichlet character modulo $4$. We note that for $\Re(s) > 1$,
$$\log L(s,\chi) = \log \prod_p \frac{1}{1 - \chi(p) p^{-s}} = -\sum_p \log (1 - \chi(p) p^{-s}) = \sum_p \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\chi(p)^k}{kp^{ks}}.$$
By the zero-free region for $L(s,\chi)$, this identity extends to $s = 1$. Furthermore,
$$L(1,\chi) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\chi(n)}{n} = \frac{\pi}{4}$$
(either by Dirichlet's class number formula or by the power series expansion of $\arctan(x)$), and so
$$\sum_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p} = \log \frac{\pi}{4} - \sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \sum_{p} \frac{\chi(p)^k}{kp^k}.$$
There are various ways to bound the second term. For example, the contribution from the term for which $k = 2$ is $\frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{2}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2} \approx -0.101$ (by Wolfram Alpha, since $\sum_p p^{-s}$ is the prime zeta function). The remaining terms can be bounded by noting that
$$\left|\sum_{k = 3}^{\infty} \sum_{p} \frac{\chi(p)^k}{kp^k}\right| < \frac{1}{3} \sum_{p > 2} \sum_{k = 3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p^k} = \frac{1}{3} \sum_{p > 2} \frac{1}{p^2(p - 1)} < \frac{1}{3} \sum_p \frac{1}{p^3} \approx 0.058$$
(again using Wolfram Alpha for the last sum). With more effort, one can of course improve this.

Comment: What is this $L$ function? I have never seen it before.

Comment: It's called a Dirichlet $L$-function; it's the most basic generalisation of the Riemann zeta function, used, for example, in the proof of Dirichlet's theorem on an infinitude of primes in arithmetic progressions, or in the proof of the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions.

Comment: Neat - I will read more about it. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I wonder if there is an elementary way, based on adapting Mertens theorem's proof from $\sum_{n\le x}\log n$ to $\sum_{a^2+b^2\le x}\log (a^2+b^2) $

Comment: @reuns I suppose there should be, since it is $4 \sum_{n \leq x} \log n \sum_{d \mid n} \chi_{-4}(d)$. You should then be able to use the Dirichlet hyperbola method.

Comment: Isn't Dirichlet's Class number formula only valid for prime modulus while you use it for 4?

Comment: @Diger it is valid for any fundamental discriminant; in this case, the fundamental discriminant is $-4$.

Comment: I guess you need to help me out on that one. The formula for the fundamental discriminant $d<0$ I found is $$L(1,\chi)=-\frac{\pi}{|d|^{3/2}} \sum_{m=1}^{|d|} m \left(\frac{d}{m}\right) \, .$$ So for $d=-4$ we have $L(1,\chi)=-\frac{\pi}{8} \left(1 - 2 - 3 + 4\right) =0\, .$

Comment: The formula you've written down is for $|d|$ prime. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_formula. In particular, take $d = 4$, and note that the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-4}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$ is $1$, while the number of roots of unity in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$ is $4$.

Comment: The book I looked into (Harold Davenport, p.50 bottom) doesn't say that these formulas are only valid for $d$ prime...

Comment: Read the first sentence of the paragraph...

Comment: "There remains the question of expressing L(l,;f) by means of a 
finite sum, as was done in §1 in the particular case when \d\ is a prime." That is refering to the analysis in §1 for prime modulus. But as I understand the sentence (formula 17 and 18) as are same for $d$ not being prime, but for which he merely states the results and refers to Landau.

Comment: But in any case, this works; the mistake you've made is that $\left(\frac{4}{2}\right) = \left(\frac{4}{4}\right) = 0$; see the definition of the Kronecker symbol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol

Comment: Also Davenport proves much earlier that $L(1,\chi)$ is never zero! So you must have known that your calculation was wrong...

Comment: "Also Davenport proves much earlier that L(1,χ) is never zero!" well yeah I knew it was wrong...Still didn't find the correct answer. So the LegendreSymbol is always zero when the upper argument is $0$ except for $\left( \frac{0}{1} \right)=\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)$? Why not in this case?

Comment: ...because $\left(\frac{a}{1}\right)$ is always $1$, since it's periodic with period $1$.

Comment: By definition you mean? I don't see why else this should be not $0$ as well?

Comment: By definition. I think these are stupid questions that you are asking...

Comment: Fair enough. The reason why I thought this for example is that $0=2^2$ mod 4, so it is a quadratic residue mod 4, but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Well,
it depends on whether
$p \bmod 4$
is 1 or 3.

What matters is
$m(x, k, j)
=\#\{\text{primes }kn+j\le x\}
$
for
$k=4, j = 1, 3
$.

It is known that,
as $x \to \infty$,
$\dfrac{m(x, 4, 3)}{m(x, 4, 1)}
\to 1
$.

From the study of "primes races"
(see [https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PrimeRace.pdf](https://dms.umontreal.ca/%7Eandrew/PDF/PrimeRace.pdf)
)
it is known that
$m(x, 4, 3)$
is usually larger that
$m(x, 4, 1)$.

However,
Littlewood showed that
there are arbitrarily large $x$
such that
$m(x, 4, 1)-m(x, 4, 3)
\ge \dfrac{\sqrt{x}\ln\ln(x)}{2\ln(x)}
$.

The following results
are known.

$m(x, k, j)
\sim \dfrac{x}{\phi(k)\ln(x)}
\sim \dfrac{li(x)}{\phi(k)}
$
(where
$li(x)$ is the logarithmic integral
and
$\phi(k)$ is Euler's phi function)
and,
as referenced in
https://primes.utm.edu/notes/Dirichlet.html,

$m(x, k, j)
- \dfrac{li(x)}{\phi(k)}
=O(xe^{-a\sqrt{\ln(x)}})
$
for $a = 1/15$.

This implies that
$|m(x, 4, 3)-m(x, 4, 1)|
=O(xe^{-a\sqrt{\ln(x)}})
$.

I believe that
this is enough to show that
the sum in the problem converges.

But I don't know for sure
and I'll leave it at this.